# Value change on check/uncheck w/ jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to switch the var "act" withing my function dynamically. I looks OK, but for some reason I keep on getting  the same **act** whether I check the checkbox or uncheck it... Can someone please take a look and see what I'm missing here?

```
$(".chkbx").change(function() {
    if($(this).attr("checked", true)) {
        var act = "remFromSessionSingleID";
    } else {
        var act = "addToSessionSingleID";
    }

    SelectedContactsInSession(act, $(this).val());          
});

function SelectedContactsInSession(act, id) {           
    $.ajax({
        url: "actions.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: "op="+act+"&contID="+id
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the `checked` attribute to `true` by passing it to [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), which then returns a jQuery object (that will always be truthy). Just get the attribute instead:

```
if($(this).attr("checked")) {
```

A better way is to use [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/):

```
if($(this).is(":checked")) {
```

Comment: Got it. Also had to change "change" to "click", did not work otherwise for some reson...

Answer (score 2):

$(this).attr("checked", true) is setting the value of $(this).attr('checked') to true every time. Remove the 2nd argument.

Also, if you use $(this).prop('checked'), it will normalize the result to boolean, while .attr() returns "checked" or undefiend:

```
$(".chkbx").change(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('checked'), $(this).prop('checked'));
});

> checked true
> undefined false
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not getting the value, you're setting it to true--that's what happens if you pass a second parameter to `attr`.